# Google sheet scrip TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Copy of Copy of Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My scrip is getting this error message.
TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Copy of Copy of Code")

```
<pre style='text-align: left; border: 1px dashed #008DEF; line-height: 18px; padding: 15px; font-size: 13px; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; overflow: auto;'>function onEdit3(e) <span style='font-weight:bold;color:#D3171B'>{</span>
var cellToStamp = <span style='color:#2A00FF'>"f2"</span> ; <span style='color:#3F7F5F'>// change to suit
</span>var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#7B0052;'>if</span>(sheet.getName() !== <span style='color:#2A00FF'>'Fleet Status Report - 0000'</span> || e.range.getA1Notation() == cellToStamp) <span style='font-weight:bold;color:#7B0052;'>return</span>;
sheet.getRange(cellToStamp).setValue(<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#7B0052;'>new</span> Date())
<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#D3171B'>}</span></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be so kind telling us what you are trying to do?
Please, could you also reformat the code in your question?

What kind of Object is 'e' in your function onEdit3(e)? I guess the Object does not contain source?

Try reading this article about Event Objects: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: I am trying to set a time stamp on cell F2 of every time some one makes changes to the sheett.

Comment: Is the function onEdit3(e) a typo? I think it should be onEdit(e).
Or are you passing the value of e from the onEdit(e) to the onEdit3(e)?

Comment: I don't know im still new to this. i was just trying to get a timestamp every time some one edits the page

Comment: What code is in the Google Script file other than the function onEdit3(e)?
What outcome did the change from onEdit3(e) to onEdit(e) gave you?